# codeigniter 3rd combo box does not display data

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, combobox

This is my Model

```
function getMatkul($dosen) {
    $data = array();
    $query = $this->db->get_where('input_jadwal', array('dosen' => $dosen));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
    }   
    $query->free_result();
    return $data;   
}   

function getKelas($matkul) {
    $data = array();
    $query = $this->db->get_where('input_jadwal', array('kode_matkul'=>$matkul)); 
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
    }   
    $query->free_result();
    return $data;   
}
```

This is my View

```
 <select name="dosen" id="dosen" class="form-control" required="">
              <option disabled="" selected="">Dosen</option>
              <?php foreach($dosen as $d){ ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $d['dosen']; ?>"><?php echo $d['dosen']; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                <select name="matkul" id="matkul" class="form-control" required="">
                <option disabled="" selected="">Mata Kuliah</option>
                <?php foreach($matkul as $m) {?>
                <option value="<?php echo $m['kode_matkul']; ?>"><?php echo $m['matkul']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>                  
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                <select name="kelas" id="kelas" class="form-control" required="">
                <option disabled="" selected="">Kelas</option>  
                <?php foreach($kelas as $k) {?>
                <option value="<?php echo $k['kelas']; ?>"><?php echo $k['kelas']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>                  
                </select>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                <button name="mysubmit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left btn-flat" type="submit">Show Record</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </section>

<script type="text/javascript">

<?php 
$this->load->model('combobox_model');
foreach($dosen as $dm) { ?>
var <?php echo str_replace(' ','',$dm['dosen'].$dm['dosen']); ?> = [
    <?php $resultM = $this->combobox_model->getMatkul($dm['dosen']); ?>
    <?php foreach ($resultM as $rm) { ?>
    {display: "<?php echo $rm['matkul']; ?>", value: "<?php echo $rm['kode_matkul']; ?>" },
    <?php } ?>];
<?php } ?> 
$("#dosen").change(function() {
         var parent = $(this).val();
        switch(parent){
            <?php foreach($dosen as $dd){ ?>
          case '<?php echo $dd['dosen']; ?>':
             lista(<?php echo str_replace(' ','',$dd['dosen'].$dd['dosen']); ?>);
            break;
            <?php } ?> 
          default: //default child option is blank
            $("#matkul").html('');  
            break;
             }
    });

function lista(array_list)
    {
      $("#matkul").html(""); //reset child options
      $(array_list).each(function (i) { //populate child options
      $("#matkul").append("<option value=\""+array_list[i].value+"\">"+array_list[i].display+"</option>");
      });
    }

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

<?php 
$this->load->model('combobox_model');
foreach($matkul as $mk) { ?>
var <?php echo str_replace(' ','',$mk['matkul'].$mk['kode_matkul']); ?> = [
    <?php $resultK = $this->combobox_model->getKelas($mk['kode_matkul']); ?>
    <?php foreach ($resultK as $rk) { ?>
    {display: "<?php echo $rk['kelas']; ?>", value: "<?php echo $rk['kelas']; ?>" },
    <?php } ?>];
<?php } ?>

$("#matkul").change(function() {
         var parent = $(this).val();
        switch(parent){
            <?php foreach($matkul as $tt){ ?>
          case '<?php echo $tt['kode_matkul']; ?>':
             listb(<?php echo str_replace(' ','',$tt['matkul'].$tt['kode_matkul']); ?>);
            break;
            <?php } ?> 
          default: //default child option is blank
            $("#kelas").html('');  
            break;
             }
    });
function listb(array_list)
    {
      $("#kelas").html(""); //reset child options
      $(array_list).each(function (i) { //populate child options
      $("#kelas").append("<option value=\""+array_list[i].value+"\">"+array_list[i].display+"</option>");
      });
    }
</script>
```

Combobox 1 linked to combobox 2, combobox 2 linked to combobox 3. when When I run it, only combo box 1 and 2 which have the data. I think the problem is on javascript. Need help, thank you. [This is the pic of my combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPtTF.png)